# AlertDialog vs AlertDialog.Builder

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Why would one use the `AlertDialog.Builder` class rather than the methods directly available to `AlertDialog`, 
For example, why use `AlertDialog.Builder.setCancellable` rather than `AlertDialog.setCancellable`? Surely this is a case of redundancy?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `AlertDialog.setCancellable` returns void and `AlertDialog.Builder.setCancellable` returns an `AlertDialog.Builder`.

This means that the builder allows you to chain a bunch of settings with a little less verbosity. It's just a convenience class

Comment: So it's 'kind of' like the istream/ostream operators in C++? That sounds reasonable

Answer (score 10):

**AlertDialog** allows you to show a dialog above your activity/fragment. It is usually used for prompting user for interaction including few buttons or notifying for something.

**AlertDialog.Builder** is an inner static class of AlertDialog which allows you to quickly setup a dialog with its handy methods. Its just like a helper class to AlertDialog. It is used for calling methods in a chain.

Comment: But who does it help? Is its purpose just to concise everything into one long statement rather than multiple individual statements (setting the title etc?) or does it offer more functionality in some way?

Comment: @stephenfin actually no - builder classes are not just for chaining method calls. they very often act like a factory which provide reasonable default values and customization options. also it's very common to for the product (`AlertDialog`) to be immutable/abstract while the factory counterparts are not which can tremendously ease the process of creating the product. take for example `StringBuilder` or `ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: @andr You make a good point about immutability. You will run into this if you create an AlertDialog with an embedded WebView (hint: use AlertDialog.Builder if you want to see changes in the loaded url).

Answer (score 1):

`AlertDialog.Builder` does the settings of the attributes such as `setTitle()` or `setMessage()` and are *not displayed* to the user.

`AlertDialog` is the one that *displays* those attributes which *have been* set in the `AlertDialog.Builder`.

The purpose of having both as mentioned somewhere is that it allows settings to be made separately from the actual displaying which in turn makes thing convenient.

Answer (score 0):

I think that factory methods are just more convinient.

Answer (score 0):

Building on jqpublic answer, more than a convenience, a builder lets you ensure the dialog doesn't exist in an unexpected or inappropriate state.
In general, a builder let's you take all the code you need to collect values, then instantiate the object only when you're ready.